# Empirical indications regarding demanded skills and tasks of data science jobs?

Tags: deep-learning, data-mining, visualization, information-retrieval, gpt

I am wondering if there are is any information about the current (and prospected) shares in skills required for advertised/existing data science jobs. This includes of course also the concrete tasks required to be done in this area.

For example I am wondering how many jobs are focused on training deep learning models vs. designing data processing architectures vs. providing concrete answers to variable data-related questions. Or information retrieval vs. supervised learning vs. data mining (extraction) vs. visualization of structured information, etc.

I think this is relevant because many people are not fully trained in all of these aspects.

I also think with the potential of a black-swan-like AI revolution based on what we are currently seeing with ChatGPT, such information would be very relevant to make some projections into the future, because some of these tasks may soon be directed to black-box AI APIs rather than humans.

Answer (score 2):

Quite general question, how you will divide your time working as a data scientist depends mostly on the job position itself, your company, and your skills.

Personally, I am not a fan of, as you say it, `black-box AI APIs` and I think people will have hard time accepting it - it's black-box.

Here's a JetBrains survey about the state of `BigData` in 2021 (not sure if there's 2022 version somewhere) that you can use to see what other people involved in data analytics are working with:

https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/devecosystem-2021/big-data/

Other useful resource could be the StackOverflow survey:

https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#overview

These are not data science specific, but I think there's enough empirical information about this sector. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. However, for example I do think people will prefer to ask something like ChatGPT "Please list all the companies mentioned in  this text" rather than waiting half a year and pay someone to develop a model that does the same thing, but worse.

Comment: Correct. I agree with you. But, consider the reliability. ChatGPT is now free. Do you know who maintains it? What if tomorrow they decide its 5$ per query? What if its performance all of a sudden degrades? Who are you going to call to fix that? :) 
 Can ChatGPT give you explanations how it works (imagine how many questions the business managers have for the technical engineers in an IT company)? It is promising, but it's way too early to tell if it is really useful

Comment: Various job adverts already featuring ChatGPT or OpenAI API experience as requirements / nice to have.